# If value is equal to NA, then estimate based on share in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, division

Consider the two following data frames:

```
df  <- data.frame(REGION   = c("REG01","REG02","REG03","REGSUM"),
                  INDUSTRY = c("INDU01","INDU01","INDU01","INDU01"),
                  VALUE    = c(NA,10,NA,30))
```

and:

```
df2 <- data.frame(REGION   = c("REG01","REG02","REG03","REGSUM"),
                  INDUSTRY = c("INDU01","INDU01","INDU01","INDU01"),
                  VALUE    = c(5,15,20,40))
```

I want to do the following calculation: If the value is equal to NA in `df`, then I want to estimate it based on the shares from `df2`. Because I know the sum in `df`, I know that I have to distribute the value `df[REGSUM,INDU01] - df[REG02,INDU01] = 30 - 10 = 20` between the two elements with NA in `df`.

Then it should divide the same elements in `df2` with the sum of the elements with NA:

```
df2_share[REG01,INDU01] = 5  / (5 + 20) = 0.2
df2_share[REG03,INDU01] = 20 / (5 + 20) = 0.8
```

This shares should be used to estimate the `NA` in `df1`. So I will end up with the following data frame:

```
    REGION  INDUSTRY   VALUE
1   REG01   INDU01     0.2 * 20 = 4 
2   REG02   INDU01     10   
3   REG03   INDU01     0.8 * 20 = 16    
4   REGSUM  INDU01     30
```

Can I do that in R (I have a lot of regions and industries in my data frame).

Comment: In the 3rd row of the expected output, isn't `0.8 * 80` wrong? Shouldn't it be `0.8 * 20`?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, of course. I will correct it.

Comment: @akrun It's `5 + 20`?

Comment: Sorry. My mistake again. It is corrected now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way.
Sum the values that are not `NA` nor `"REGSUM"` in `df`. Use this value to compute the total to assign to the `NA` values. Then get the values in `df2` corresponding to the `NA` entries and compute the proportions to assign.

```
not_na_values <- sum(df$VALUE[df$REGION != "REGSUM"], na.rm = TRUE)
to_assign <- df$VALUE[df$REGION == "REGSUM"] - not_na_values

na <- is.na(df$VALUE)
numer <- df2$VALUE[na]
denom <- sum(numer)
df$VALUE[na] <- numer/denom * to_assign

df
#  REGION INDUSTRY VALUE
#1  REG01   INDU01     4
#2  REG02   INDU01    10
#3  REG03   INDU01    16
#4 REGSUM   INDU01    30
```

---

The function below generalises the code above for data.frames with many industries. It works by splitting the input data.frames by industry and `lapply`ing the previous code, written as a function to each split list member. In the end it reassembles these sub-dataframes and returns to caller.

```
assign_na_values <- function(x, y,
                             region_col = "REGION", 
                             industry_col = "INDUSTRY",
                             value_col = "VALUE", 
                             regsum = "REGSUM") {
  f <- function(x, y, region_col, value_col, regsum){
    i <- x[[region_col]] != regsum
    not_na_values <- sum(x[[value_col]][ i ], na.rm = TRUE)
    to_assign <- x[[value_col]][ !i ] - not_na_values
    
    na <- is.na(x[[value_col]])
    numer <- y[[value_col]][na]
    denom <- sum(numer)
    x[[value_col]][na] <- numer/denom * to_assign
    x
  }
  sp_x <- split(x, x[[industry_col]])
  sp_y <- split(y, y[[industry_col]])
  res <- lapply(seq_along(sp_x), function(i){
    f(sp_x[[i]], sp_y[[i]], region_col, value_col, regsum)
  })
  res <- do.call(rbind, res)
  row.names(res) <- NULL
  res
}

assign_na_values(df, df2)
#  REGION INDUSTRY VALUE
#1  REG01   INDU01     4
#2  REG02   INDU01    10
#3  REG03   INDU01    16
#4 REGSUM   INDU01    30
#5  REG01   INDU02    30
#6  REG02   INDU02     6
#7  REG03   INDU02     4
#8 REGSUM   INDU02    40
```

**New test data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  REGION = c("REG01","REG02","REG03","REGSUM","REG01","REG02","REG03","REGSUM"),    
  INDUSTRY = c("INDU01","INDU01","INDU01","INDU01","INDU02","INDU02","INDU02","INDU02"), 
  VALUE = c(NA,10,NA,30,30,NA,NA,40)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  REGION = c("REG01","REG02","REG03","REGSUM","REG01","REG02","REG03","REGSUM"), 
  INDUSTRY = c("INDU01","INDU01","INDU01","INDU01","INDU02","INDU02","INDU02","INDU02"), 
  VALUE = c(5,15,20,40,10,30,20,60)
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, what if I have INDU02 as well in my dataset? How do I then change the code when I still want the same result for INDU01?

Comment: @Michael Can you post a more complete data sample? Anyway, I would `split` the data by industry, `lapply` the code above to each sub-data.frame and then combine everything back to one df.

Comment: @Michael See the edit, I believe that it can process many industries.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base R solution

```
idx <- which(REGION == "REGSUM")
df <- transform(
  df,
  VALUE = replace(
    VALUE,
    is.na(VALUE),
    prop.table(df2$VALUE[is.na(VALUE)]) * (VALUE[idx] - sum(VALUE[-idx], na.rm = TRUE))
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  REGION INDUSTRY VALUE
1  REG01   INDU01     4
2  REG02   INDU01    10
3  REG03   INDU01    16
4 REGSUM   INDU01    30
```

Answer (score 2):

If there multiple 'INDUSTRY', we could do a join and use group by operations

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("REGION", "INDUSTRY")) %>% 
  group_by(INDUSTRY) %>%
  transmute(REGION, INDUSTRY, VALUE = case_when(is.na(VALUE.x) ~ 
    VALUE.y/sum(VALUE.y[is.na(VALUE.x)]) * (VALUE.x[n()] - 
         sum(VALUE.x[-n()], na.rm = TRUE)), TRUE ~ VALUE.x)) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  REGION INDUSTRY VALUE
#  <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>
#1 REG01  INDU01       4
#2 REG02  INDU01      10
#3 REG03  INDU01      16
#4 REGSUM INDU01      30
```